# Bit manipulation Hexadecimal C++

Tags: c++, hex, bit-manipulation

I have an unsigned int and a hex value. I want to be able to check if the unsigned int contains the hex value; e.g:

```
unsigned int reason = 0x80020002

#define MAJOR_ERROR_CODE 0x00020000
#define MINOR_ERROR_CODE 0x00000002
#define OPTIONAL_ERROR_CODE 0x80000000
```

Now as we can see, the variable reason has all of the three #define error code. I need to be able to detect the presence/absence of the hex Error Codes int the variable reason. How do I do it?

Edit 1 : Apologies all, I guess I posted a slightly different question when I tried to simplify it and post. What I have is a couple of Major, Minor and Optional Error codes - For Eg

```
#define MAJOR_ERROR_CODE_1 0x00020000
#define MAJOR_ERROR_CODE_2 0x00010000
#define MAJOR_ERROR_CODE_3 0x00070000

#define MINOR_ERROR_CODE_1 0x00000002
#define MINOR_ERROR_CODE_2 0x00000004
#define MINOR_ERROR_CODE_3 0x00000006

#define OPTIONAL_ERROR_CODE_1 0x80000000
#define OPTIONAL_ERROR_CODE_2 0x50000000
#define OPTIONAL_ERROR_CODE_3 0x30000000
```

Now my unsigned int is a combination of these three error codes. Each of these error codes have a unique string and depending on which one of these is present in my variable reason i need to generate the string.

Comment: You have 3 errors (major, minor, optional) why do you need an entire int (assuming 32 bits) to store those three? Why not just use a uint8_t and pick three bits and if they are set, you have errors, if they are not, you have no errors? You could test for individual errors or a combination of any or all three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these are single bit codes, it's as simple as

```
 if ((reason & MAJOR_ERROR_CODE) != 0)
 {
     // this is a major error
 }
```

However I suspect it's actually a mask, e.g.

```
 #define MAJOR_ERROR_MASK 0x7fff0000
 if ((reason & MAJOR_ERROR_MASK) == MAJOR_ERROR_CODE)
 {
      // this is a major error
 }
```

Comment: Hey thanks. This works. Can you explain me or point me to resources which let you know how to use masks. In your example I don't understand why you have used a mask of 0x7fff0000. I just used a mask of 0x000f0000 for the Major error code where the fourth digit from left is set and it worked fine.

Comment: @EternalLearner Think of how bitwise `AND` works. Another answer includes a link to some resources that you can use, but you may find it useful to experiment. First, read the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) and then write a small program that will do bitwise operations for you, displaying their actual result. Try doing some of the examples on paper, compare your results to the program you wrote. For example, `(0x0030 & 0x00F0)` returns true (since 3 = 0011 and F = 1111 -> 0011 & 1111 = 0011, and that is not zero.)

Comment: (sidenote for clarification: I wasn't claiming that 0x0030 = 3 or that 0x00F0 is equal to F. I should have made that more explicit in my original comment - which can no longer be edited).

Comment: Thanks everyone who beat me to replying. That was meant to be the mask for the upper part of a Windows HRESULT, the facility code, in case that's what this actually was - but I got it wrong: that should have been 0x0fff0000 for three hex digits only.

Answer (score 3):

By using the binary operator `&`:

```
if(reason & MAJOR_ERROR_CODE)
{
    // Do Major Error code...    
}

if(reason & MINOR_ERROR_CODE)
{
    // Do minor Error code...    
}

if(reason & OPTIONAL_ERROR_CODE)
{
    // Do Optional error code...    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely looking for [bitwise-AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND)

[C++ info here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html)

Answer (score 0):

Something like so:

```
const bool isErrorCodeSet = reason & MAJOR_ERROR_CODE;
//...and so on
```

You can see this works basically by manual and operation:

```
  80020002
& 00020000 
------------
  00010000
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i got the question correct but looks like can check with & operation

e.g.

```
((reason & MAJOR_ERROR_CODE) != 0)
{

//Do what you want to do for MAJOR_ERROR_CODE

}
```